# how to use isms to send a SMS

Tags: android, sms, root

I am trying to use `isms` in a root shell to send a SMS but still no luck. I have tried

```
service call isms 4 s16 "+mynumber" s16 "" s16 "hello world!" s16 "" s16 ""
```

but I am seeing this in the LogCat and SMS is not going out from the device.

```
W/Parcel  ( 1056): Attempt to read object from Parcel 0x52ecfdac at offset 124 that is not in the object list
```

Is there a way to send a SMS using Shell without using `SmsManager` to do this..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "smsHere" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Where CCXXXXXXXXXX is country-code followed by phone number.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This approach will bring the SMS app to the foreground. I am interested in sending the SMS out without showing the UI.

Comment: This isn't possible unless you've created an app that can respond to an intent to send SMS without showing UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command (it works for me) :
service call isms 5 s16 "PhoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "BodyText"

Comment: no working with me .. how to set the permission? even I used SU privilege, but no success :( ..im using kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

For me ***service call isms***, didn't work. I developed an application for two different chipsets, Mediatek and Spreatrum. For Mediatek(MTK), I found there API which is addon, which contains SMSManagerEx, that can send sms in dual sim. But for spreadtrum there was no API so I had to use reflection as mentioned by Maher in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351936/how-to-send-a-sms-using-smsmanager-in-dual-sim-mobile/30677542#).
I have my comment there as well, that sends sms from specific sim from code without prompting the default sms app.