# Send SMS via adb shell service call isms Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, shell, service, sms, adb

Currently I send SMS by this command:

> adb shell service call isms 6 s16 "phoneNumber" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "smsText"

in Android 2.3.6 and works perfectly.

Now I want to use the same command in Android 4.1.2 but when I send the command I received this output in Logcat

```
> 12-11 14:17:37.97 1626-2182/? D/PhoneRestrictionPolicy﹕ SmsRestrictionPolicy.canOutgoingSms >>>>
```

Anyone Can help me to remove this "SmsRestrictionPolicy" please?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043490/how-do-i-send-an-sms-from-a-shell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending a SMS on Android through ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580199/sending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11414616/763080):

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Where CCXXXXXXXXXX is country-code followed by phone number. This may not work correctly on non-standard android installations, you will need to find the correct keyevent values to pass.

---

From comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846128/how-to-use-isms-to-send-a-sms) it appears that sending via `service call isms`, as mentioned in the question, is not possible (though I would bet it *is* possible if your app is set as the default SMS app for the device).

---

One work-around to sending an SMS without user interaction would be to send the number and message to a server that sends SMS messages. There is likely already a third party tool for this. At quick glance, [this](http://www.nowsms.com) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `telnet` and `sms send` commands.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325836/870674).

Answer (score 1):

## My Environment：

- Android 4.1.2
- MIUI ROM

you can try this.

Switch to the message application user before `service call isms ..` command.

> su u0_a34 \
>   service call isms 5 s16 "10086" i32 0 i32 0 s16 "11"

`u0_a34` is the user name of the message application.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try it

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because in android 4.1.2 the isms number is 5 and not 6. 
So it's :

```
adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+01234567890" s16 "+01000000000" s16 "Hello world !" i32 0 i32 0
```

You could check how to do it for any android version here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224091/4896841)